# React Native css-what high severity vulnerability

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-ui-kitten

### Context

In my react-native application, I am getting a high severity vulnerability regarding a package called css-what. In which it apparently is resulting in 4 other vulnerabilities because they directly or indirectly depend on css-what. Here's the following output I get on the console from after executing `npm audit`

```
css-what  <5.0.1
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-native-svg@9.12.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/css-what
  css-select  <=3.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of css-what
  node_modules/css-select
    react-native-svg  >=9.13.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/react-native-svg
      @ui-kitten/components  >=5.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native-svg
      node_modules/@ui-kitten/components
      @ui-kitten/eva-icons  >=5.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native-svg
      node_modules/@ui-kitten/eva-icons
```

So as you can see from the output, the css-what causes a vulnerability for the package `react-native-svg` and because the design system I installed `ui-kitten` depends on `react-native-svg` it subsequently has a vulnerability.

I looked up on the css-what package and the vulnerability in which can be seen [here](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754). I know that the vulnerability has a high severity because it can result in denial of service.

### What I tried

I made a duplicate of my project because I know running `npm audit fix --force` would result in breaking changes in which it did when I ran that command on the duplicate project. The app was able to build but it threw an error when running on the simulator.
(Note that I am developing from a bare react-native project).

The instructions that the documentation gave was to update css-what to 5.0.1 but I have no idea on how to go about doing that. Hence I hope someone is able to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above approach for my angular project, but its considering css-what as a diff dependency instead of dependency inside package @angular-devkit/build-angular.

````
12.1.0-next.6
| `-- css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.0.1
|   `-- cssnano@5.0.6
|     `-- cssnano-preset-default@5.1.3
|       `-- postcss-svgo@5.0.2
|         `-- svgo@2.3.0
|           `-- css-select@3.1.2
|             `-- css-what@4.0.0
`-- css-what@5.0.1 ```
 
tried, see in above. its taking separate css-what thats should not be the case.
still the issue exists.
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I do the following:

I checked online the latest version of css, which has no vulnerabilities, and installed it as --save.

`npm install css-what@5.0.1`

then install npm-force-resolutions:

`npx npm-force-resolutions`

add to my package.json:

`"resolution": {"css-what": "^ 5.0.1"}`

and then install dependencies as usual:

`npm install`

---

if you receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid Version: ^5.0.1
```

then just erase the ^ in the package.json and retry npm-force-resolution and install.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem updating css-what `npm update css-what` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

css-what in its version prior to 5.1.0 has [DOS attack vulnerability](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754/). You can find that in your package-lock.json that this is a transitive dependency coming from css-select.

You need to first install the non-vulnerable version of your dependency , so in this case

```
npm install --save css-what@5.0.1
```

Once that is done you need to add resolution strategy in your package.json. So , just add below key at the end of your package.json

```
"resolutions": { "css-what": "^5.0.1" }
```

After this just run `npm install` and run `npm audit` to see if your fix is working. You can cross check your package-lock.json to verify the new entry.